# Disable Default Security Group attachment to ENI in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-security-group, elastic-network-interface

ECS service is using EC2 instances and ENIs are attached to EC2 instances. Is there any way to prevent the default Security group to be not attached to those ENIs and just the custom Security groups attached?

Comment: Did you enable ENI trunking? For me, that seems to be the cause for the extra ENI (which is expected) which is attached to the default security group (which is unexpected).

Comment: With enabling the ENI trunking. An extra ENI is attached to default security group. Is there a way to attached it to custom security group in cloudformation?